# Searching List<string> based on string match

Tags: c#, list, search

I have the following c# `List<string>`

```
var lists = new List<string>
{
    "a", "b", "c", "ee", "ja"
}
```

I now want to find the index of the last item whose alphanumeric value is less than or equal to `d`, which in this case would be 2 - which represents "c"

Can anyone suggest how I can do this? It needs to be fast as it will be searching large lists.

Is there also a way to do the same comparison for the closest match to `"ef"` or any set of multiple characters

EDIT - I know I could write a for loop to do this, but is there any other way to do this? Maybe a built in function.

I know if it was a numeric function I could use Linq.

Comment: _of the first item_ really first? So why not "a" it also less than "d". Maybe you want to get last item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [FindLastIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findlastindex?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_FindLastIndex_System_Predicate__0__)

```
var index = lists.FindLastIndex(value => value.CompareTo("d") < 0);
```

NOTE: You have to use `CompareTo` as `<` doesn't exist for strings.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get great performance by using the [`BinarySearch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=netframework-4.7.2) method, under the condition that your `List` is sorted. If it isn't, then don't use this method because you'll get incorrect results.

```
// List.BinarySearch returns:
// The zero-based index of item in the sorted System.Collections.Generic.List`1,
// if item is found; otherwise, a negative number that is the bitwise complement
// of the index of the next element that is larger than item or, if there is no
// larger element, the bitwise complement of System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Count.
int pos = lists.BinarySearch("d");
int resultPos = pos >= 0 ? pos : ~pos - 1;
Console.WriteLine("Result: " + resultPos);
```